# CI2 Dompdf return blank tabs when deploying to server Centos

Tags: php, centos, codeigniter-2, dompdf

I'm creating a pdf feature for my project. Using CI2 and Dompdf. Everthing is normal when I run this project in my local laptop that using windows 11. But when I deploy it to server which is using Centos it return blank page.

This is my file in `apps/backend/libraries`:

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once('apps/backend/third_party/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class ToPdf 
{
    protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci = &get_instance();
    }

    public function generate($view, $data = array(), $filename = "", $paper = "A4", $orientation = "portrait")
    {
        $html = $this->ci->load->view($view, $data, TRUE);

        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $dompdf->setPaper($paper, $orientation);

        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf", array("Attachment" => FALSE));
    }
}
```

And this is the generate pdf method that I created:
`apps/backend/modules/cppt/controllers/cppt.php`

```php
<?php 
class Cppt extends CI_Controller {
    var $webconfig;
    var $moduleid = 401;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('ToPdf');
        $this->load->helper('common');
        $this->load->helper('operator');

        $this->load->model('CpptModel');
        $this->load->sharedModel('PendaftaranModel');
        $this->load->sharedModel('LoginModel');
        if (!$this->LoginModel->isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect(base_url() . 'login');
        }

        $this->webconfig = $this->config->item('webconfig');
        $this->module_name = 'cppt';
    }

    function index()
    {
        redirect(base_url() . $this->router->class . '/listing');
    }

    function listing($page = 0)
    {
        if (!checkRole(array($this->moduleid))) {
            redirect(base_url() . 'dashboard');
        }

        $tdata = array();
        $ldata['content'] = $this->load->view($this->router->class . '/index', $tdata, true);
        $this->load->sharedView('template', $ldata);
    }

    ...some code ...

    function generate_pdf($idPendaftaran) {
        $idMedrec = $this->CpptModel->getIdMedrec($idPendaftaran);
        $data = array();
        $data = $this->CpptModel->getCppt(['id_medrec' => $idMedrec]);
        $data['imgUrl'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents(base_url().'public/template/backend_template/img/logo_hs_better-removebg-preview.png'));
        $this->topdf->generate('pdf_view', $data);
    }

}
```

And this is my pdf file:

```html
<style>
    .soap {
        text-align: left;
    }

    tr > td {
        text-align: center; 
    }
</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Catatan Perkembangan Pasien Terintegrasi</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>theme/img/hi.png">

    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img style="width: 49%;" src="data:image/png;base64, <?= $imgUrl; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- <hr style="border-top: 1px solid black; height: 0px; margin-bottom:25px"> -->
        <div style="border-color: #555555;
            border-top-width: 2px;
            border-bottom-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 0;
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            ">
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Catatan Perkembangan Pasien Terintegrasi</h3>
        <table style="border: 1px solid;">
            <tr style="border-bottom:  solid thin;">
                <th width="15%" style="font-size: small; text-align:center; border: 1px solid;"><?= $this->lang->line('label_tanggal_cppt');?></th>
                <th width="10%" style="font-size: small; text-align:center; border: 1px solid;"><?= $this->lang->line('label_profesi_cppt');?></th>
                <th width="40%" style="font-size: small; text-align:center; border: 1px solid;"><?= $this->lang->line('label_soap_cppt');?> <br>
                    <small style="font-weight: 500;"><?= $this->lang->line('label_soap_desc_cppt');?> </small>
                </th>
                <th width="20%" style="font-size: small; text-align:center; border: 1px solid;"><?= $this->lang->line('label_instruksi_cppt') ?></th>
                <th width="15%" style="font-size: small; text-align:center; border: 1px solid;"><?= $this->lang->line('label_nama_cppt') ?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;"><?= isset($cppt['tanggal_pemeriksaan_perawat']) ? $cppt['tanggal_pemeriksaan_perawat'] : '-'; ?></td>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;">Perawat</td>
                <td class="soap" style=" border: 1px solid;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            S: <?= $keluhan_utama_perawat ?>
                            <?= isset($alergi['alergi_obat']['nama']) ? ('<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Alergi Obat : '.$alergi['alergi_obat']['nama']) : '' ?>
                            <?= isset($alergi['alergi_kandungan_obat']['nama_kandungan_obat']) ? ('<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Alergi Kandungan Obat : '.$alergi['alergi_kandungan_obat']['nama_kandungan_obat']) : '' ?>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <?= $alergi_lainnya ?? '' ?>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            O: Tinggi Badan: <?= $tinggi_badan  ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Berat Badan: <?= $berat_badan ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tensi: <?= $tensi_sistole .'/'. $tensi_diastole ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nadi: <?= $nadi ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Respirasi: <?= $respirasi ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saturasi Oksigen: <?= $spo2 ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Suhu Badan: <?= $suhu ?> <br>
                        </li>
                        <li>A: <?= $diagnosis_perawat ?></li>
                        <li>P: <?= $planning_perawat ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;"><?= nltobr($instruksi_perawat) ?></td>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;"><?= isset($perawat['fullname']) ? $perawat['fullname'] : '-'; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;"><?= isset($tanggal_pemeriksaan) ? $tanggal_pemeriksaan : '-'; ?></td>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;">Dokter</td>
                <td class="soap" style=" border: 1px solid;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            S: <?= $anamnesa ?>
                            <?= isset($alergi['alergi_obat']['nama']) ? ('<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Alergi Obat : '.$alergi['alergi_obat']['nama']) : '' ?>
                            <?= isset($alergi['alergi_kandungan_obat']['nama_kandungan_obat']) ? ('<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Alergi Kandungan Obat : '.$alergi['alergi_kandungan_obat']['nama_kandungan_obat']) : '' ?>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <?= $alergi_lainnya ?? '' ?>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            O: Tinggi Badan: <?= $tinggi_badan  ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Berat Badan: <?= $berat_badan ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tensi: <?= $tensi_sistole .'/'. $tensi_diastole ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nadi: <?= $nadi ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Respirasi: <?= $respirasi ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saturasi Oksigen: <?= $spo2 ?> <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Suhu Badan: <?= $suhu ?> <br>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            A: <ul style="display: inline-table;">
                                <?php foreach($diagnosis as $key => $value): ?>
                                    <li><?= $value['penyakit']['nama'] ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            P: <?= $planning ?>
                            <?php if(count($terapi)>0): ?>
                            <br>Terapi:
                            <ul>
                                <?php foreach($terapi as $key => $value): ?>
                                    <li><?= $value['obat']['nama'] ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if(count($tindakan)>0): ?>
                            <br>Tindakan:
                            <ul>
                                <?php foreach($tindakan as $key => $value): ?>
                                <li><?= $value['detail']['nama'] ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;"><?= nltobr($instruksi_dokter) ?></td>
                <td style=" border: 1px solid;"><?= isset($dokter['nama']) ? $dokter['nama'] : '-'; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
</body>
```

I don't know what happened. Any solutions for that problem?

Comment: I don't think the OS has anything to do with this, it's your PHP code you need to look at, and specifically the errors it generates. Without those errors we cannot really be of much help. See: [Where does PHP store the error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have checked log error in the nginx server. But there's no error

Comment: Just to make sure you're actually looking at the log that holds the PHP errors, you could run a script that generates a known PHP error. For example: [A PHP syntax error](https://3v4l.org/EvIMp). You're looking at the wrong log if you don't see that error.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have deployed the application to Ubuntu server and it works. Maybe I miss some dependencies are needed in Centos server to run DOMpdf. Thank you for your response.